# Azure DevOps Pipeline - Fail build for CA1502 CA1505

Tags: azure-devops, continuous-integration, msbuild-task, code-metrics

I am pretty new to Azure DevOps and this might be a very trivial or very specific question. However I could not find a concrete answer anywhere.

I have setup the build pipeline for My C# codebase and enabled Code analysis.
This pipeline is configured to run on Every PR as a branch policy.

**The Goal**: Capture code analysis response and Look for [CA1502](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/code-quality/ca1502?view=vs-2019) and [CA1505](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/code-quality/ca1505?view=vs-2019)
If the value of these is outside the threshold, Fail the build.

I explored the [Build Quality Checks Plugin](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=mspremier.BuildQualityChecks), but it doesn't seem to have such a configuration

Answer (score 0):

You can easily do that with the [NDepend Azure DevOps extension](https://www.ndepend.com/docs/azure-devops-tfs-vsts-integration-ndepend).

The extension can [fail the build thanks to the notion of quality gate](https://www.ndepend.com/docs/quality-gates#BuildFailure).

The tool proposes [several rules related to type and method complexity and maintainability](https://www.ndepend.com/default-rules/NDepend-Rules-Explorer.html?ruleid=ND1003#!).

Thresholds in these rules can be adjusted to your need since [a rule is a C# LINQ query easily modifiable](https://www.ndepend.com/docs/write-your-own-code-rules).

[image: Azure DevOps Quality Gate Build Failure]

Comment: Thanks for the response, we are considering ndepend as an alternative option,but also looking for scripting and alternative options